# sort Mongodb find() output according to regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, sorting

```
db.restaurant_info.find({name:/pi/i})
```

Above mongodb query is returning the data from DB in the below format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579cf26204aba69a41da82ad"),
    "name" : "pizza hut",
    "type" : "restaurant"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579cf26204aba69a41da82af"),
    "name" : "Kai pi",
    "type" : "restaurant"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579cf26404aba69a41da82c7"),
    "name" : "pizza and pasta",
    "type" : "restaurant"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579cf26504aba69a41da82d0"),
    "name" : "Crispi chicken",
    "type" : "restaurant"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579cf26504aba69a41da82d1"),
    "name" : "Pita house",
    "type" : "restaurant"
}
```

However, this query will be used for auto-population so if I use `pi` in the search text field, then all the recodrs start with `pi` should come before other records, e.g sequence I am expecting:

> ```
> Pizza hut
> Pizza and pasta
> Pita house
> Kai pi
> Crispi chicken
> ```

if I modify the query with `db.restaurant_info.find({name:/^pi/i})`,
then it returns

> ```
> Pizza hut
> Pizza and pasta
> Pita house
> ```

without

> ```
> Kai pi
> Crispi Chicken
> ```

Please guide me which query should I use to get the sequence I am expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you would do this with **find()**, but you could do it with **aggregate()**.

First you'd use your regex for the **$match**, then you could use **$project** with **$substring** and **$eq** to project a field indicating whether you have a prefix match.  You could then use that field to sort your results.  Here is an example.  I also used **$toLower** so that your sorting would be case insensitive.

```
{
    $match: {
        name:/pi/i
    }
}, 
{
    $project: {
        name:true,
        regex_match: {
            $eq: [
                "pi", 
                { $substr: [ {$toLower: "$name"}, 0, 2 ] }
            ]
        }

    }
}, 
{
    $sort: {regex_match:-1}
}
```